# awk + how to manipulate awk output

Tags: awk, sed, rhel

The following awk command prints the results from services file

```
# awk '{print $2}' /etc/services 


48002/tcp
48002/udp
48003/tcp
```

How can I manipulate the output so it prints the "service file" before each line? Something like:

```
 # awk '{print $2}' /etc/services .......

 service file 48002/tcp
 service file 48002/udp
 service file 48003/tcp
```

Comment: Try: `awk '{print "service file", $2}' /etc/services`.

Comment: I don't understand, do you want the specific string "service file" or the name of the service as reported in `/etc/services`? If the latter, is `cat /etc/services` enough?

Comment: Taliezin answer is OK ,

Comment: You probably want to also skip lines that begin with `#` or are empty, to avoid nonsense outputs `service file Note` and `service file` e.g. `awk '!/^#/&&NF {print "service file",$2}' /etc/services`

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{ print "service file", $2 }' /etc/services
```

To avoid empty lines and lines that only have comments:

```
awk '/^[a-z]/ { print "service file", $2 }' /etc/services
```